# Why is it that renaming the NavMenu component in the shared folder breaks my CSS

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I was trying to test some changes to my NavMenu component by creating a new one (With a different name) and adding the changes there but I soon noticed that my CSS wasn't loading properly anymore.

From the console I noticed that the new file wasn't referencing {Assembly}.styles.css

The same issue persists when I simply rename the NavMenu component.

A search on the whole solution for NavMenu didn't yield any results outside of the MainLayout which is where it is being used.

Answer (score 1):

The NavMenu CSS is Nested under NavMenu.razor and has the same name NavMenu.razor.css, at least in Dotnet 6.0 and I think that CSS file nesting is valid from Dotnet 5.0. Which is called CSS isolation.

Styles in this isolated file are applied only to the file it is nested. So by creating a new razor page, you need to attach a new CSS file if you want to use styles from an isolated CSS.

(Doc from Microsoft aspnet about css-isolation)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#enable-css-isolation

Comment: I don't think that's it.

Say the original was NavBar.razor then scoped CSS is NavBar.razor.css 
New one TestNavBar.razor then scoped CSS TestNavBar.razor.css still doesn't work.

Comment: I think there is something else wrong with my solution. Thank you.